# Wordpress Admin - Add Edit link to specific page under Pages Menu

Tags: pages, wp-admin

I am trying to add direct links to edit specific pages, under the Pages menu:

[image: Example]

Currently I am using, which give me the menu item / link:

```
add_pages_page( 'Hero', 'Hero', 'read', '15', '' );
```

However when I click it, the page is blank with the following URL:

```
edit.php?post_type=page&page=15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpse182102_register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function wpse182102_register_my_custom_menu_page() {
    add_pages_page(null, 'Menu Item Name', 'edit_posts',/* or whatever capability required for this object */ '/post.php?post='.get_page_by_title('Etusivu')->ID.'&action=edit', null, '');
}
```

And change *Etusivu* to be the name of the page you want to edit.

Comment: Awesomesauce! I replaced `get_page_by_title()` with `get_page_by_path()` as I am using slugs to hook things up. Thank you :D